# Ordering / grouping posts by datepicker ACF

Tags: php, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, date-time

I'm currently ordering a bunch of events based on a datepicker from ACF. They are all grouped per month, so all events of October are all listed together, than November, December and on. I only have one problem with the formatting of the datemonth.

Before each new month the name of the month is in a , but the name of the month is in English, while I would want it to be in Dutch (because of the website is Dutch and so is the WordPress install. I have tried changing:

```
$month = $date->format('F');
```

To

```
$month = $date->echo date_i18n('F');
```

But this is not what it should be and I'm not sure to what to change it to. Below is the full query / grouping of the posts, but if someone could give me the final shot on how to display the name of the month correctly, much appreciated.

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'cat'           => '-1',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'      => '_expiration-date',   
));

$group_posts = array();
    if( $posts ) {

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $date = get_field('datum-concert', $post->ID, false);

        $date = new DateTime($date);
        $year = $date->format('Y');
        $month = $date->format('F');
        // $month = $date->echo date_i18n('F');

        $group_posts[$year][$month][] = array($post, $date);
    }}

    foreach ($group_posts as $yearKey => $years) {
    foreach ($years as $monthKey => $months) {
        echo '<h2 style="text-transform: capitalize;">';
        echo $monthKey;
        echo ' ';
        echo $yearKey;
        echo '</h2>';

    foreach ($months as $postKey => $posts) { ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'concert-single' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile;
    }}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you were trying to use echo as a method of *DateTime* object.

`$month = $date->echo date_i18n('F');`

It should be:

`$month = date_i18n('F', strtotime( $acf_date ) );`

Where `$acf_date` is the time string not the *DateTime* object.

Comment: Hi Greg,

The change does infact display the name of the month correctly, but it does break the wrapper for each month. It now only displays 1 (the current) month. All other events, that are in november, december and so one are all listed, but the wrapping with the <h2>+ name of the month are gone.

Comment: You are using month names as table keys so you probably are passing the wrong time string to the `strtotime( $acf_date )`. Try this: `$month = date_i18n('F', strtotime( get_field('datum-concert', $post->ID, false) ) );`

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution for this. It has been on my to-do list forever but had trouble finding a solution. Thank you so much!